# forward declaration of std::string and std::wstring

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, forward-declaration, stdstring

The problem of the inability to forward declare std::string and std::wstring is often discussed. As I understand, the reason is that those types are typedefing  of instantiation of template class basic_string:

```
namespace std {
  typedef basic_string<char>    string;
  typedef basic_string<wchar_t> wstring;
}
```

And forward declaration of a typedef isn't allowed by the language.

Wouldn't it be better for the c++ standard using inheritance instead of typedef:

```
namespace std {
  class string : public basic_string<char> {};
  class wstring : public basic_string<wchar_t> {};
}
```

So that way we could forward declare std::string and std::wstring?

Comment: Why do you need to forward-declare them? `#include <string>` takes care of any declarations just fine.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid - the `#include <string>`

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the `#include`?  There are other ways to improve compile speed; take a look at precompiled headers.

Comment: as a rule of thumb. if it has templates: it's hard to forward declare. if you inherit from a template class it doesn't make the forward declaration easier. in general the `stl` is too loosely defined to be forward declared safely.

Comment: You don't know if the Intel compiler supports precompiled headers.... Did you check the documentation? Or ask Google? Looks like pch support is there, and not new. Any version from the last decade will have it.

Comment: @Alex: huh? Forward declarations don't list base classes, so they don't get more complex when the base classes are templates.

Comment: @BenVoigt if you want to inherit from some class `base` you cannot use a forward declaration of `base`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Wouldn't be better for the c++ standard using inheritance instead of typedef [...]

No.

The std::basic_string is not meant to be inherited in any form. This limitation allows the implementation of a std::basic_string, that is much cheaper (faster) to create and destroy, as it has no virtual function table.

If you need std::[w]string to be defined, just `#include` it.

**Edit** (answering comment)

One of the guiding principles of C++ (and the standard library) is "do not pay for what you do not use". This means the code is written in such a way, that you should not incur runtime costs for features you do not need.

Creating a std::string instance would be much more expensive if each instance had a virtual table (and this would make using std::string, prohibitive in performance-critical code).

Instead, std::string is intended as a fast, type-safe, RAII implementation of the C `char*` mechanism. Similarly, you should not attempt to inherit from std::vector, list, map, shared_ptr, unique_ptr and so on.

If you really need a string base class, consider writing a `your_namespace::[w]string_base` yourself (a trivial implementation would be one that encapsulates a `std::[w]string` internally).

Comment: virtual function table exists only if at least one virtual function is defined

Comment: That is correct, but because in the case of inheritance you _need_ a virtual destructor (to avoid getting into UB), allowing for the inheritance of a `std::basic_string`, in practice this means at least 'define the class with a virtual destructor'.

Comment: > The std::basic_string is not meant to be inherited in any form.

Can you give a reference or explanation for that? not "just because"

Comment: @utnapistim: No, inheritance does not need a virtual destructor in every case.  Only when polymorphic deletion is needed.

Comment: @BenVoigt, technically yes, but that implies that specializations will not implement polymorphic delete. Such a requirement is much more difficult to impose on client code (than "do not inherit"), from the point of view of the library writer. On top of that, nobody expects it (so you are increasing the "WTF/SLOC" ratio of your code).

Answer (score 3):

A "typedef derived class" is not equivalent to a real typedef.

Imagine I have a function that should work with both versions:

```
template <typename Ch>
void foo(const std::basic_string<Ch>& s) {
  // do some stuff here
}
```

And the stuff I need to do includes calling 3rd party function `bar`, which exists as overloads for `std::string` and `std::wstring`, but not as a template:

```
void bar(const std::string& s) {}
void bar(const std::wstring& s) {}
```

Then if you have a true typedef, that will just work. If you use inheritance instead, it will either fail to compile, or it will silently create copies of the strings to pass to `bar`, which is a hidden performance trap.

Or take the `substr` member function. It returns the same type as it is called on, but that means if it is a member of `basic_string`, it doesn't return a `string` or `wstring` if those aren't true typedefs. That leads to all sorts of subtle issues.