# C++ string forward declaration is ambigious

Tags: c++, string, forward, declare

I tried to forward declare std::string but it does not seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
namespace std
{
    template<typename>
    class allocator;

    template<class _CharT>
    struct char_traits;

    template <typename _CharT, typename _Traits = char_traits<_CharT>, typename _Alloc = allocator<_CharT>>
    class basic_string;

    typedef basic_string<char> string;   
}
```

Including string results in this error: `reference to ‘basic_string’ is ambiguous`. Is there any way forward decleare string without errors?

Comment: You are not allowed to forward declare names inside of `std`

Comment: No, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476181/forward-declaration-of-stdstring-and-stdwstring) as to why this is not possible, and why you get this error.

Comment: Oh. Well, when I was including "bits/stringfwd.hpp" it worked in gcc, because of that I thought I could do that.

Comment: @DasOhmoffSan As a general rule, you should never write a forward declaration for types you don't own. If you want to forward declare something from a library, you want the library writers to provide a forward declaration file for you, similar to the `iosfwd` header that the standard library provides

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way forward declare std::string without errors?

No.

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit has chastised me for putting full and complete answers in the comments.  This is a full and complete answer, albeit without explanatory prose.  BobMorane's link provides the explanatory prose.  This question should be closed as a duplicate, in my opinion, and refer to that link.